# ¿Porque me sale "Se excedieron los recursos del sistema" C# Access?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, ms-access

estoy trabajando con c# y access,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi codigo:

```
foreach (var item in alumnos)
                    {
                    OleDbDataReader reader = Connection.Read("SELECT * FROM Estudiante WHERE cod=" + item.cod);
                    if (reader.Read())
                        {
                        }
                    else
                        {
                        MSAConnection.execute("INSERT INTO Estudiante (cod,tipoEstudiante,nombre,Paterno,Paterno,nombreCompleto,grado,paralelo,cel,CelT,codColegio) " +
                        "values (\""
                        + Convert.ToInt32(item.cod) + "\",\""
                        + tipoEstudiante + "\",\""
                        + item.nombres.ToUpper() + "\",\""
                        + item.Paterno.ToUpper() + "\",\""
                        + item.Paterno.ToUpper() + "\",\""
                        + item.nombrecompleto.ToUpper() + "\",\""
                        + getGrado(item.grado) + "\",\""
                        + getParalelo(item.paralelo).ToUpper() + "\",\""
                        + Convert.ToInt32(getNumero(item.cel)) + "\",\""
                        + Convert.ToInt32(getNumeroTutor(item.CelT)) + "\",\""
                        + Convert.ToInt32(item.colegio) + "\")");
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Por favor, podrias ser mucho mas claro en lo que quieres hacer? mas alla del error, podrias explicar que tratas de hacer, y si el problema ocurre siempre?

Comment: trate de hacer un insert para 1000 registros y me sale el erro de **se excedieron los recursos del sistema** -  trato de hacer un insert y el problema ocurria cada vez que llegaba a os 500 registros

Answer (score -1, accepted):

si abren un read() no olviden cerrarla.

```
foreach (var item in alumnos)
                    {
                    OleDbDataReader reader = Connection.Read("SELECT * FROM Estudiante WHERE cod=" + item.cod);
                    if (reader.Read())
                        {
                        }
                    else
                        {
                        MSAConnection.execute("INSERT INTO Estudiante (cod,tipoEstudiante,nombre,Paterno,Paterno,nombreCompleto,grado,paralelo,cel,CelT,codColegio) " +
                        "values (\""
                        + Convert.ToInt32(item.cod) + "\",\""
                        + tipoEstudiante + "\",\""
                        + item.nombres.ToUpper() + "\",\""
                        + item.Paterno.ToUpper() + "\",\""
                        + item.Paterno.ToUpper() + "\",\""
                        + item.nombrecompleto.ToUpper() + "\",\""
                        + getGrado(item.grado) + "\",\""
                        + getParalelo(item.paralelo).ToUpper() + "\",\""
                        + Convert.ToInt32(getNumero(item.cel)) + "\",\""
                        + Convert.ToInt32(getNumeroTutor(item.CelT)) + "\",\""
                        + Convert.ToInt32(item.colegio) + "\")");
                        }
                        if(reader != null) reader.Close();
                    }
```

Comment: Esto parece mas un comentario que una respuesta.

Comment: Al parecer se respondió él mismo: supongo que eran muchos registros los que quería guardar, y abrir una conexión tras otra agotaba los recursos del sistema. La otra opción (mejor aún) es la respuesta de Leandro.

Comment: asi es, son muchos registros y a mi codigo le faltaba cerrar `if(reader != null) reader.Close();` para cerrar el siclo del `read`, encontre una solucion buscando

Answer (score 3):

No se  como implementas `Connection.Read()` pero esta claro que sino permite parametros debes dejar de usarlo.

Podrias utilizar algo como ser:

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("connection string"))   
{   
    conn.Open();  

    string sql = @"INSERT INTO Estudiante (cod,tipoEstudiante,nombre,Paterno,Paterno,nombreCompleto,grado,paralelo,cel,CelT,codColegio)
                    VALUES (@cod, @TipoEstudiante, @nombre, ...)"
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand (sql, conn);

    foreach (var item in alumnos)
    {
        if (!ExisteEstudiente(item.cod))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cod", Convert.ToInt32(item.cod));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TipoEstudiante", tipoEstudiante);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", item.nombres.ToUpper());

            //resto parametros

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

veras que el command se define una unica vez y luego se asignan parametros durante cada iteracion del `foreach`

Ademas se hace uso de un metodo para validar si existe

```
public bool ExisteEstudiente(string cod)  
{  

    string sql = @"SELECT * FROM Estudiante WHERE cod = @cod";   

    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("connection string"))   
    {   
        conn.Open();  

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand (sql, conn);   

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cod", cod);   

        int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());   

        return count == 0;   

    }   

}
```

de esta forma el codigo queda prolijo y mantenible, es importante definir la conexion dentro del using

Comment: me gusta tu respuesta @LeandroTuttini eres bueno en esto, bueno en mi caso trate de reducir codigo la mas que pude, utilizando pocos recursos.

Comment: pero a veces reducir codigo no es buena idea, podrias pensar un desarrollo en capas, el acceso a datos se deberia realizar en una capa de datos y no todo junto

Comment: Elegante solución (y disminuye algunos problemas de SQL Injection).

Answer (score 0):

Hola me presento el mismo mensaje con access solo que yo estaba tratando de cambiar el tipo de dato de la columna de numerico a texto ...

la solucion fue sacar copia a la tabla que tenia la informacion y la copia dejarla vacia solo estructura , despues pase la info de la original ala copia..

termino ok...
Espero te sirva...para mi fue que la tabla tenia demaciada informacion .

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).